# Do you need internet connection to use Amazon rekognition or can it be used in offline app?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rekognition

I would like to make an app that can utilize facial recognition from Amazon rekognition (AWS). Is internet connection required to use Amazon rekognition?

Comment: Yes. Rekognition is a web service accessible via API.  It is not a standalone application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All AWS services are accessed via the Internet.

Your application will need to make an API call to AWS to process the picture/video. The benefit is that the computer/device using Rekognition does not require much process/memory because that is all done in the cloud.

Answer (score 0):

John, you could try and batch store them locally but you will need to eventually connect to the internet.